# what do you call a place where someone thought of an idea?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm working on a project about structures and their historical value. I don't need this information, however, I would like to know and/or have it exposed to people that have wondered the same question.

Comment: If I rule out *government*, that just leaves a *think-tank*? The *bathtub* ("Eureka!")? The *brain*?

Answer (score 13):

You can call it the *birthplace* of the idea. Merriam-Webster defines *birthplace* as "place of birth or origin" [[link](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/birthplace)], and one of its examples is "New Orleans is regarded as the *birthplace* of jazz" [ibid].

Answer (score 7):

we often use **cradle** as the conceptual word for where an ideology was nurtured (usually by more than one person or over a period of time) for example for civilisations we say

**Cradle of civilization** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cradle_of_civilization

it can be used for innovation

**Cradle of Innovation** http://www.leeds-sdg.com/cradle-of-innovation/

Comment: I think "cradle" tends to be used for more grandiose concepts, and isn't as common as "birthplace" (e.g. Bell Labs is the birthplace of the transistor, I've never heard anyone talk about its cradle).

Comment: I think the distinction is, cradle fits things that slowly developed over a longer period of time (which do tend to be more grandiose or abstract)